# Expression language & data-image - not show image

Tags: html, image, thymeleaf, el

I'm using Thymeleaf (Spring Boot project). I have the code:

```
<div class="single_product_thumbnails">
    <ul>
        <li class="active"><img th:src="${product.mainImage}" alt="" data-image="${product.mainImage}"/></li>
        <li><img th:src="${product.imageSecond}" alt="" data-image="${product.imageSecond}"/></li>
        <li><img th:src="${product.imageThird}" alt="" data-image="${product.imageThird}"/></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Th:src load image thumbnail in left panel (EL code works). Data-image load image on the center of screen - code not work i.e. if I use data-image="http://image.png" or data-image="images/single_2.jpg" it works but my EL expression doesn't work.

Original code (fully works - from https://colorlib.com/etc/coloshop/single.html):

```
<div class="single_product_thumbnails">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/single_1_thumb.jpg" alt="" data-image="images/single_1.jpg"></li>
        <li class="active"><img src="images/single_2_thumb.jpg" alt="" data-image="images/single_2.jpg"></li>
        <li><img src="images/single_3_thumb.jpg" alt="" data-image="images/single_3.jpg"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

How to use EL properly in this data-image example? Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thymeleaf only evaluates attributes that are prefixed with `th:`.   You should be able to use:

```
<div class="single_product_thumbnails">
    <ul>
        <li><img src="images/single_1_thumb.jpg" alt="" th:data-image="${product.mainImage}" /></li>
        <li class="active"><img src="images/single_2_thumb.jpg" alt="" th:data-image="${product.imageSecond}" /></li>
        <li><img src="images/single_3_thumb.jpg" alt="" th:data-image="${product.imageThird}" /></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The other option would be to use `th:attr`, to dynamically generate the attribute you want.  Like this:

```
<img src="images/single_1_thumb.jpg" alt="" th:attr="data-image=${product.mainImage}">
```